# core data save records using to-many relationship?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In my app i've `to-many` relationship between entity `Survey` and `SurveyAction`.I'm using `Survey` in multiple view controllers(step 1, step 2, etc) on each step i've multiple `SurveyAction` for a `survey`.But when i retrieve records i got SurveyAction that i inserted last only. i.e. if i insert two action on step 1 and 3 records at step 2, i got only three records that i inserted in step 2.
Here is my Data model-

```
 Survey.h
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
    @class SurveyAction;
    @interface Survey : NSManagedObject
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *actions;
    //some other properies of survey object
    @end
    @interface Survey (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
    - (void)addActionsObject:(SurveyAction *)value;
    - (void)removeActionsObject:(SurveyAction *)value;
    - (void)addActions:(NSSet *)values;
    - (void)removeActions:(NSSet *)values;
    @end
```

and

```
SurveyAction.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@class Survey;
@interface SurveyAction : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * action;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * deadline;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * responsible;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * surveyId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * step;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Survey *survey;
@end
```

What i'm doing wrong here? Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

**Edit:-** I can have multiple records(survey), i got list of survey and i pass the selected survey to next VC when i select a row.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Survey* survey = [listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    ParticularsViewController* vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"particularsView"];
    vc.survey = survey;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

and in next VC to ensure i get right survey i'm using predicate and save my data-

```
-(void)rightbuttonPressed
{
 Survey* survey;
    NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Survey"
                                        inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];

    // check whether the entity exists or not
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(SELF = %@)", self.survey]];

    // if get a entity, that means exists, so fetch it.
    if ([self.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error])
        survey = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] lastObject];

    // if not exists, just insert a new entity
    else survey = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Survey"
                                                inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    //surveyAction
    if (actionsArray.count > 0) {

        NSMutableSet* actionsSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
        for (Action* obj in actionsArray) {

            SurveyAction *actionDescription = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SurveyAction"
                                                                            inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

            [actionDescription setValue:@"1" forKey:@"step"];
            [actionDescription setValue:obj.action forKey:@"action"];
            [actionDescription setValue:obj.person forKey:@"responsible"];
            [actionDescription setValue:obj.deadline forKey:@"deadline"];

            [actionsSet addObject:actionDescription];
        }
        [survey setValue:actionsSet forKey:@"actions"];
       // survey.actions = actionsSet;
    }
    if (! [self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
        NSLog(@"Couldn't save data to %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]));
}
```

And this is how i fetching records

```
-(void)populateView
{
 int counter = 0;
    for (SurveyAction *sAction in self.survey.actions) {
        if ([sAction.step isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

            Action* action = [[Action alloc] initWithObject:sAction];
            [self addrowView:action withframeorigin:198+(counter*40)];
            counter++;
        }

    }
}
```

But as i said i got only those `SurveyAction` records which i added last.

Comment: do you save your context?

Comment: yes, i've edited the question to show saving context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this line

```
        [survey setValue:actionsSet forKey:@"actions"];
       // survey.actions = actionsSet;
```

you are replacing the existing actions, not adding to them.  Use

```
[survey addActions:actionsSet]
```

Instead

Comment: OMG!! i suppose to change all my data structure, you saved me from lot off hard work!!